# Issue with tabletool of datatable with pdf, csv, xls and copy options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools

```js
sTable = $('#s').dataTable({
        "bVisible":"True",
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',        
        "tableTools": {           
            "sSwfPath": "https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.1.1/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",            
            "aButtons": [ 
               "copy", 
               "csv", 
               "xls",            
               "pdf",
               "print",
               "select_all", 
               "select_none" 
            ]
        }
});
```

Buttons are showing fine, but copy,csv,xls,pdf are not working, i am not getting any 404 , i have checked in browser console, but i am loading total datatable  and buttons 's container dynamically with a filter button. it may cause problem,, please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution, and it is working fine..
The problem was that my buttons are in hidden, so while intialisation time it was not getting the height and widht of my tabletool button's. So i created a function on call back funtion which add the width and height of the buttons.

```js
funtion m(){
  $('[id^=ToolTables_] embed').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).attr('width','47px');
  $(this).attr('height','47px');       
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your browser Adobe Flash Player plug-in is disabled, disabled for that particular page or is not installed at all.

- Enable flash in chrome -> **https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en**
- Enable flash in FireFox -> **https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-firefox.html**
- Enable flash in IE -> **https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/install-flash-player-windows.html**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have ebnabled the flash in my chrome, still these buttons are not working..